# "Alēctō" or "Allēctō"?

Tags: names, vowel-quantity, aeneis, vergilius

"Alēctō" is the name of one of the Furies, made surprisingly famous in the *Harry Potter* books. It seems to come straightforwardly from Greek *[ă](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/8746/406)-* "not" + *lēg-* "stop" + *-tos* "[adjective]", so "unstoppable" or "unstopping".

However, Vergil refers to this Fury as "Allēctō", with an extra L. For example, see Aeneid X.41:

> *Allēctō mediās Italum bacchāta per urbes*
>   Allecto, running wild throughout all the cities of Italy

Is there any linguistic or historical reason for this extra "L"? It certainly makes the name easier to fit into a hexameter, but Vergil could just as well have lengthened the vowel, like we see in I.2 (where he has *Ītaliam* for *Italiam*). And I'd expect Vergil of all people to know his Greek backward and forward, given his love of Homer.

EDIT: [As sumelic points out](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/8746/406), if my etymology is correct, the *a* in *Alēctō* would be short by nature.

Comment: You might also link to the question"[Hexametric Greek names](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7689/hexametric-greek-names)", which is about variation in Greek between different forms of names for the sake of poetry. One of the examples mentioned in b a's answer is Achilles' name, which apparently could have one or two lambdas.

Comment: For what it's worth, Ovid and Pliny also write _Allecto_. I have no evidence for this, but could the extra "l" be related to the adjective (and given name) _allectus_ "chosen, recruited"?

Comment: Alecto with a single L [is attested](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23alecto%23) too, but metric evidence shows that the first syllable is still heavy/long. Variations between *āl-* and *ăll-* are metrically irrelevant. What is the length of the Greek alpha?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Good question! As far as I can tell it's the "privative alpha", but I don't know how long that alpha was…I'll ask another question about that, since it's relevant on its own.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva The mention in Pliny is especially interesting, given that he was writing prose, so it wouldn't be for metrical reasons. I wonder which sources he was working from?

Comment: In Latin, the much more frequent spelling variant seems to be Allecto. Alecto is extremely marginal.

Comment: Basically, it boils down to this: why do we have Ἀλληκτώ (Lucian) or Ἀληκτώ in Greek? This could be difficult to answer, with such an extremely low number of attestations in Greek (TLG shows 3 only, Ἀληκτώ). cf. ἄληκτος (cf. **poet.** ἄλληκτος, Montanari)

Comment: That being said, the TLL headword is Allecto, where we can read that "in recentioribus codicibus Alecto"