# A list of common different spelling-variants

Tags: resource-request, spelling

The beginner (like me) might occasionally find a word he is not familiar with. It is usually easy to retrieve the base-form (nom. or stem for a verb) and find it in a dictionary. Even more, there are tools today (like Wiktionary or [William Whitaker's Words](http://archives.nd.edu/words.html)) that exact the base-form themselves.

Yet sometimes it simply does not work. I suspect in many cases this is because the author adopts a different spelling than the regular. Examples:

1. *appellarunt* for *appellaverunt*  (this kind of shift - like others - is [supported](http://archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?keyword=appellarunt) in Words).
2. Adding "st" (which I still not sure as to what this signifies) as in "agitandum**st** vigilias (Pl. Trin. 869)
3. Real-life example: The word *praecipe* in "Occumbunt multi letum ferroque lapique aut intra muros aut extra praecipe casu" (Enn. Ann. 391 Vahl). 
   If you search *praecipe* using the tools mentioned, you get the imperative of praecipio which is clearly not the case here. It rather looks like the abl/adv of "praeceps" - I assume it is a some kind of spelling derivation(?), that might occur in other cases as well.

So the question is: Is there a kind of list of spelling contractions/suffix/prefix that are less-regular, yet common enough?

**Edit:**

I now see that [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=agitandumst&la=la) supports the first two examples

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

Your first example is called a **contracted perfect** or **syncopated perfect**.

When the perfect stem of a verb ends in a vowel plus *V*, and the ending starts with a short vowel, the *V* and the first vowel of the ending can be removed. For example, *amāverunt* > *amārunt* "they loved", *delēvisse* > *delēsse* "to have removed", *audīveris* > *audīris* "you might have heard".

Occasionally, the *V* disappears, but the second vowel doesn't. In this case, both vowels end up short (*). This is most common in poetry; Vergil for example often uses forms like *audieram* (from *audīveram*, "I might have heard") to fit the meter.

Perseus is generally very good at recognizing these, so I'd trust that over Whitaker's Words.

(*) In native Latin words, a vowel before another vowel is almost always short. When you see a long vowel before another vowel, it's usually in a loanword from Greek, like *Aen**ē**as*. [See this question for more information.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/14259/406)

Your second example is **elision**. When one word ends in a vowel (or a vowel plus M), and the second word starts in a vowel (or a vowel plus H), one of those vowels disappears and they're pronounced as a single word.

This is most important in poetry, and usually isn't written out: the middle of Aeneid I.3 is written *multum ille et* but pronounced *mult' ill' et*. In almost all cases, the first vowel is the one deleted. (And you probably know all this already if you've done anything with Latin poetry.)

However, if the second word is *est*, the *second* vowel is deleted instead. And this is often written out explicitly: *multum est* would be written *multum'st* or *multumst*. If you see an unexpected *st* at the end of a word, it's a contraction of *est*. (If it helps, you can think of it in the same category as the enclitics *-que*, *-ve*, and *-ne*.)